# How do I pass variable from a Jade template file to a Javascript file?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Im very new to Node.js and trying to get my head round few things.How do I pass variable from a Jade template file to a JS file?

I have got this line of code in my server.js file

```
res.render("aws.jade", {data : JSON.stringify({'val' : 'This is a Test'})});
```

Basically Im just trying to get values in **data** to aws.jade template file

And this is aws.jade

```
html
    head
       script(type='text/javascript')
            var data = !{data}
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
        title Title
        h1 Heading
        #div.test
```

I keep getting this error in the Firebug console:

```
<var>data = {"val":"This is a Test"}</var>
```

Could someone please explain as to why this is happening and a way for me to pass variable from a Jade template file to a JS file?

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a `.` character after the script, this tells Jade that you want a block of text inside a tag.

Here's your updated code.

```
html
    head
        script(type='text/javascript').
            var data = !{data}
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
        title Title
        h1 Heading
        #div.test
```

**EDIT - To set title to data.val**

First you should change your response, remove JSON.stringify so you're returning an object not a string value.

```
res.render("aws.jade", {data : {'val' : 'This is a Test'}});
```

Then you should be able to access the data objects attributes and structure directly using dot notation, and assign it straight to the title element like this...

```
title= data.val
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,out of curiosity if I want to set the Title to val in data,how do I do it? I tried doing this in the jade file:- title !{data.title} but its not working

Comment: I'll edit the answer, comments too restrictive for clear formatting.

Comment: thanks once again,its getting clearer now.If I was to remove JSON.stringify and return an object not a string value, will I still be able to assign it to javascript variable? is it possible to set  a variable in javascript with the value of data and also set the title to data.val ? do you want me to post this as a separate question? thanks

Comment: Yes, update your script and replace `data = !{data}` with `var data = !{JSON.stringify(data)};` .  This will parse the data object client side for javascript assignment and still allow your template engine a model to parse.

Comment: thank you ever so much with your help ,much appreciated