# Unable to pass data to html from mongo/mongoose node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to build a checklist app that takes input from a form and then writes it to a collection. The problem is that, when I try to print the input on the same page I took it from, it does not reach the JavaScript in the html.

If I `console.log(checklist_data);`, I see all the data from mongo. How do I get it to the page?

routes/index.js:

```
//insert into the db ( works perfectly)
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var checklist_model = mongoose.model('checklist_model');

exports.create = function (req, res) {
    new checklist_model({
        name: req.body.name,
        comment: req.body.comment
    }).save(function (err, checklist_model) {
        res.redirect('/checklist');
    });
    // query db for all checklist items ( checklist_data has all the data )
    exports.checklist = function (req, res) {
        checklist_model.find(function (err, checklist_data, count) {
            res.render('checklist', {
                title: 'checklist',
                checklist_data: checklist_data
            });
            console.log(checklist_data);
        });
    };
}
```

HTML:

```
//HTML code
<script language="javascript" class="lookhere">
    checklist_data.forEach( function( checklist_model ){
    checklist_model.content
});
</script>
```

app.js:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/checklist', routes.checklist);
app.post('/create', routes.create);
```

Comment: What are you rendering the pages with? Jade? EJS?

Comment: Yes, the app is using jade. Since I am learning I tried to use the HTML script tags to see how the output gets displayed. Apologies if that is not the correct approach.

Comment: Try passing the variables to `p` tags first and rendering them as text. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239105/how-do-i-pass-variable-from-a-jade-template-file-to-a-javascript-file) for how to do that. (Just to make sure jade is seeing the variables you're passing it.)

Comment: I was doing some searching about how to do it in Jade and I tried,                                                            ul                                                                          each item in checklist_data                                         li #{item.name}                                                           I am getting this error :Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. I will try what you just suggested. Thanks Luxelin.

Comment: I just did a test with your suggestion and I see the entire collection under `script(type='text/javascript'). var data = !{checklist_data}`.Sadly I am unable to display just name and comment.